# Rails 3 - Before form submission human check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, session

I've got a simple message form (:name, :title, :body) that has a recaptcha. When I have both my form and recaptcha on the same page I don't get the same user experience because my server-side form model validations don't work like i'd like them to. So I was thinking of implementing a redirect to a seperate recaptcha page before the form attributes get saved into my database.

I was wondering what are the best practices for this situation? Should I send a session of the message attributes to another controller that handles the recaptcha? If that's the case, I'm a bit lost on how to go about that. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why having the recaptcha on the same page messes with your model validations. The recaptcha input shouldn't be getting sent to the model in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is to create an additional model attribute, an integer with a name like `submission_step`, with values corresponding to what step the user got to in the submission process. In this case there are only two:

```
0: before recaptcha
1: after successful recaptcha
```

So when the user first submits the form, a new message is instantiated with a `submission_step` of `0`, validations are run and assuming they pass the "uncaptcha'd" message is created. The user is then sent the recaptcha page. If they do the recaptcha successfully, the record is updated to change the `submission_step` attribute to a `1`.

You can then use `submission_step` as a scope to filter for forms that have passed the recaptcha step. You can also validate based on the step using `:if` or `:unless` conditional options in `validate`.

Of course this creates records in the database for forms that have not passed the recaptcha step, which might be a problem -- although you could periodically clean them out. But I've found it's a fairly clean solution and makes it easy if you want to add additional steps to the process in the future.

Comment: I did what you said about the submission_step integer and used Wicked Wizard for the steps. Works awesome now! Thanks again

Comment: Oh didn't know about Wicked Wizard, looks interesting.