# Rails spec: Template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rspec

I'm trying to create an Order model for receiving orders, based on Michael Hartl's User model in his tutorial.

I've created a basic Order page and Confirmation page, both in the Orders directory in View. I created tests for content, and when I run them, they show all sorts of errors, most having to do with this:

```
Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }
  ActionView::Template::Error:
      No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders"}
```

Which I figured had to do with missing view (cause of "template"), but as I said, I've got those files. In my routes.rb file, I have the following:

```ruby
resources :orders

root to: 'alpha#welcome'

match '/order', to: 'orders#new'

match '/about', to: 'alpha#about'
match '/contact', to: 'alpha#contact'
match '/confirmation', to: 'orders#show'
```

And my Order controller says this:

```ruby
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end
end
```

I've been combing through his tutorial to try to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but nothing's working yet. Help? I'm very new to this.

Oh. Additionally confusing is that rspec claims it's having this problem in a spec document that doesn't try to follow either of those routes at all. (I've got three specs: one for static pages, one for the order model, and one for the order pages. The static page one is complaining about the action in the order model controller.)

Thanks, as requested, here's my order pages spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Order Pages" do 

    subject { page }

    describe "order page" do
        before {visit order_path}

        it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Order Below') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Order') }

    end

    describe "confirmation page" do
        let(:order) { FactoryGirl.create(:order) }
        before { visit confirmation_path(order) }

        it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Your order:') }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Order') }
    end

end
```

Comment: Also, that `match '/order', to: 'orders#new'` looks really wrong in your routes, you shouldn't need that if you have the resources route.

Comment: So it's as I thought, your `visit order_path` will fail if you don't pass it an actual order. You need to create one as you do in the confirmation page spec and then pass it to `order_path` in your before block.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused. So the way I do it in the confirmation page spec is correct, and I should do similarly in the controller?

Comment: And cut out the match '/order', to: 'orders#new'?

Comment: Ah. I think I've got it. Add what I've got on the confirmation spec to the order spec. And should I cut out the route to the confirmation page as well? Or is that not included in the resource route?

Comment: So I just tried all that (took out the match to #new, added @user on the route for confirmation -- didn't want to add user specification to the order page spec, cause it's the same for all users) and it didn't work. Ideas?

Comment: I don't really know where to start. You need to first review what a "resource" is. "orders" are definitely your resources in this case. If you want to add a confirmation step, you might want to see this answer I posted earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918270/rails-3-before-form-submission-human-check/11918530#11918530 However, I think I've answered your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error you're getting you're missing an `:id` in your route, so I suspect you're not including the order as an argument when calling `order_path` in your specs (it would be helpful if you'd include the spec code).

You should call the path for any member actions (`show`, `update`, `destroy`) in your specs like this:

```
visit order_path(@order)
```

(I'll add more to this answer once you post the spec code.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, by the way. I'm all mixed up on this. Spent the last hour or two making tiny changes and rerunning the spec to no avail.

Comment: So thinking more about this, I think that shouldn't (ideally) be the fix, actually, because the Order page is sort of a sign-up page. It isn't at all differentiated by user. So there isn't (again, ideally) any page like Order/1, although I'm trying to have individualized confirmation pages.

Comment: "order/1" is not the page for the *user* with id 1, it's the page for the *order* with id 1. So I don't understand why you keep mentioning "differentiated by user". The show page would be the same for all users.

Comment: Yeah. I'm confusing cause I'm confused, sorry. There is no "User" model for my site at this point. "Users" (meaning people on browsers) place "orders" that go into the database. I'm trying to make the /order page be a page with forms where these "users" can update the database by placing orders. So that page would be the same for everyone. Then, they'd be directed to a /show or /confirmation page that printed out their order for them (at this stage).

Comment: At any rate. Thanks a lot for the replies. I'll check that post out. I'm just not sure if I'm communicating or understanding correctly. I've only be working with rails for a few days, so most of this goes over my head.

Comment: No worries, it takes a bit of time. FWIW, what you're trying to do is a multi-step form, so you're right that an id should not be necessary until the resource (order) is actually created. Pls do check my earlier answer, and also you might want to see wicked wizard: http://schneems.com/post/18437886598/wizard-ify-your-rails-controllers-with-wicked

Comment: In a nutshell, the basic problem is that rails will forget all the form values when it goes to the confirmation page unless you store them somewhere. You can do that either by temporarily saving the (unconfirmed) order after the first step, by passing the form values as query parameters to the next action, or by saving them in a session cookie. I prefer the first technique (which I described in the earlier answer).